# fb_temp not appearing on orca/cache folder

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, facebook-messenger

I tried to recover my facebook messages that were deleted around a month ago using the ES File Explorer. So I went to Internal Storage > Android > data > com.facebook.orca > cache. The forums stated that there should be the fb_temp folder there, but there's none. Version is 5.0 and is not rooted.

Do I have to root my phone first?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score -1):

> Do I have to root my phone first?

Yes, you need to root the phone to see apps' private data files in internal storage.